# DialogFlow name in context, prevent resetting conversation flow every time a new name is spoken

Tags: dialogflow-es, chatbot

I have a conversation tree set up in DialogFlow, starts with a welcome intent and has a few follow-up intents, goes three levels deep.
The conversation begins with the user saying hi or similar, to which the bot replies with a greeting and prompts for the user's name, the user then provides the name, the bot follows up with 'Hi [name], nice to meet you' and asks a question. Then depending on the answer (custom follow-up intents) the conversation goes on.

The name is remembered and used in the follow-up intents, but at any point in the conversation flow if the user says a different name for some reason (or something that is recognized as a name), the bot resets to the 'awaiting_name' intent and says 'Hi [new name], nice to meet you'.

How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Can you update your question to show screen shots of the Intents that you currently have created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due the the LifeSpanCount that you are setting to each intent. Reduce it to 1 or 2 as required so to make it inactive after 2 counts.
Also, you can add follow-up intents to handle the "no-match" situation, defining whether to repeat the intent or do something else when a user speaks something out of context.

Comment: Hi Riddihi, thank you for providing your input. While this might be a solution to a similar problem, there is no way of knowing if this is the actual solution for the issue with the information that is currently in the question. For instance it could also be caused because no context is set at all on the first intent, so we would need to know more about the issue before we could provide a proper answer.